# very weird running result of Qt

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I got a really weird problem.

I have a Qt for Android code. It was working very well. But this week
when i run it, it suddenly had a weird problem.

The problem is that: Even  i comment or remove all the code in
the main function. only left:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

But the running result is same as before i remove all the code in the
main function. It seems Qt creator didn't save my change.

I tried : 1) restart computer 2) change the Android device 3) clear the
project and re-running it. No matter what i do , the program has the
same running result.

Did u encounter this weird problem before? what's the possible cause?

Comment: What is the "running result" you are seeing?

Comment: "Running result" is the what i got before i changed the code.

Comment: Is the executable file actually copied on the device ? (compare the size/date of the file with the one you just recompiled).

Comment: Run qmake again and then build

Answer (score 0):

This is because of previously generated moc files and .o files are still there.

Go to the build path of your project in terminal, change to superuser and then run `make clean` for cleaning all those files, then build the project from QtCreator and run it. Bingo!!

This is because qt-creator try to clean all binaries, but it sees it doesn't have the permission to  clean all those files. Normally this happens while copying a source form one location to some other.